# Is the series $\sum \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} (2x + 1)^n$ convergent? absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the series $\sum \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} (2x + 1)^n$ convergent? absolutely?

Can someone hint me which theorem should I use to analyse that? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: notice that when applying ratio test for $\frac{(n!)^{2}}{(2n)!}$, you should obtain this $\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {n+1}{2\,n+1}}.$

Answer (score 4):

As said in the comments, by the ratio test you have $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n)! ((n+1)!)^2 } {(2(n+1))! (n!) ^2 } = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^2 } {(2n +1)(2n+2) } = \frac {1} {4}$$
Thus the series converges uniformly and so absolutely (and pointwise) when $ 2x+1 \in (-4,4)$, which is for $x \in (-\frac{5}{2}, \frac{3}{2}) $
The series does not converge when $2x+1 = +4$ or $-4$, because using Stirling formula $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^2 (4^n)} {(2n)! } =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {(4^n)(2\pi n) (\frac{n} {e})^{2n} } {( \sqrt{4 \pi n} ) )(\frac{2n} {e} )^{2n}} = +\infty $$